# Implementing a shared variable for all the threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, maven, thread-safety

I am implementing a project which requires all the tests to update on to a particular variable.
Is there a way to implement a shared variable which can be accessed by all the threads (during the parallel testing using Maven)?

If so, please share your ideas with me?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13582395/sharing-a-variable-between-multiple-different-threads

Answer (score 1):

First, define a class which contains such variable, or it could be inside your thread (derived) class as well.

```
class Particular {
    static int count=0;
    public static synchronized static inc(){
        count++;
    }
    public static synchronized int getCount(){
        return count;
    }
}
```

Then, you can access the count using `Particular.inc();` or `Particular.getCount();`
More advanced, you could use Singleton design pattern to ensure thread-safe.